# Postgres Conditional Sum Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Given the following table `mileage`, I should perform two sums for each `vehicle_id`: once summing all entries for `miles` and another - all entries for `miles` only where `is_processed = false`.

##### mileage

| vehicle_id | miles | is_processed | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 773 | 800 | f | 2023-04-17 13:11:59.100846 |
| 767 | 200 | f | 2023-04-24 11:29:52.503024 |
| 767 | 100 | t | 2023-04-11 15:14:33.125348 |
| 773 | 200 | t | 2023-04-11 15:49:34.313639 |
| 767 | 150 | f | 2023-04-24 11:43:31.496871 |

This would be simple enough with one of two methods:

##### Method 1

```
select vehicle_id,
  sum(miles) as total,
  (select sum(miles) from mileage t2 where t1.vehicle_id = t2.vehicle_id and is_processed = false) extra
from mileage t1
group by vehicle_id;
```

##### Method 2

Fetch all records and compute with a single `for` loop in my language of choice.

##### Desired solution

However, I want to know if there is a way to do all of that with PostgreSQL. I already tried window functions and could not figure it out, and grouping would involve a second scan of the same table which will hurt performance given that I expect to be processing hundreds of thousands of rows.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a "conditional aggregate" which is really just putting a case expression inside the aggregate function.

```
SELECT vehicle_id
    ,sum(miles) AS total
    ,sum(case when is_processed = false then miles else 0 end) AS extra
FROM mileage t1
GROUP BY vehicle_id;
```

Keep in mind the case expression evaluates to a value on each row, so the aggregate is still just summing values.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a subquery. Use the aggregate with filter

```sql
select
    vehicle_id,
    sum(miles) as total,
    sum(miles) filter (where not is_processed) as extra
from mileage
group by vehicle_id;
```

Read in the docs: [Aggregate Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)